# Can I do a check if user responds then update boolean to true?

Tags: c#, console, boolean, user-input, readline

I want to create a piece of code that sets a boolean variable to true if the user responds through Console.ReadLine. This variable comes to use later in some other code. The only code I've tried so far is:

```
bool hastyped = false;

var input = Console.ReadLine();
hastyped = true;
```

How can I make this work?

For reference the actual code that I'm using goes something more like:

```
response = Console.ReadLine();
hastyped = true;
```

That is, after initialising the variables of course.

Comment: And if the user just types the enter key without typing any other key? Do you consider it as  a valid response? Or if the user just types a series of spaces?

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` will only return if the user pressed (at least) the enter key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see if the User actually inputted something you can check the string you save the Input into.

Because when you hit the Enter Key, `Console.ReadLine` is an empty string. So you can check with [`.IsNullOrEmpty()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=netcore-3.1) to see if the Input actually contains any characters.

Or you could even use [`.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=netcore-3.1), to check if the Input contains only Whitespaces as well.

**Example:**

```cs
// Getting Input from Console
string input = Console.ReadLine();

// Check if Input contains more than whitespaces and isn't empty or null,
// if it doesn't bool is true else it's false
bool hastyped = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like this? basically it checks if the value is null if not then it changes it to true.

```
            bool hastyped = false;

            var input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (input != null) 
            {
                hastyped = true;
            }
```

or you can use this way as well, you can find more information about it from microsoft docs

```
            bool hastyped = false;
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) 
            {
                hastyped = true;
            }
```

Comment: One liner: _bool hastyped = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(input);_